# Problem with Syntax, getting Run TIme error

Tags: excel, vba, file, pdf, save

I'm trying to save a file as a PDF but I'm getting a

> Run-Time error '1004'

I can write excel file no problem, when I change code to write PDF file I get this error.

I've tried to write the syntax several ways to no avail.  I'm thinking I'm missing a parameter maybe??  I've look at multiple examples and I don't see what I'm doing wrong.

---

CODE::::>>>>

```
fileName = "O:\Paula\Z test write PDF file exhibit A\" & Cells(initial + 1, 1).Text & ".pdf"

Set DestBook = Workbooks.Add

With DestBook
    .Title = "Installment Trans History"
    .Subject = "legal Request"
    .SaveAs fileName:=fileName, FileFormat:=xlTypePDF 
    Set DestSheet = .Worksheets("sheet1")
End With

Set DestSheet = DestBook.Worksheets("sheet1")
```

If I change the file to .xlms and remove the `FileFormat:=xlTypePDF`  the file is created as expected.

When I change the file to .pdf and add , `FileFormat:=xlTypePDF` I get the run time error.  I've tried moving things around but I just get the same error.

Comment: What happens if you remove the `.pdf` from the file name and use the `FileFormat:=xlTypePDF`. I think you are doubling with the file extension.

Comment: What is the value of the cell you are concatenating into the file name?

Comment: Same error, Run-Tune error '1004'

Comment: my file name is the account number 1058105.  that works file when I create an XLMS file.

Comment: I think you want to use ```workbook.exportasfixedformat``` not ```.saveas``` Here is a link: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.workbook.exportasfixedformat

Comment: thank you I'll give that a try

Comment: Tried the .ExportAsFixedFormat and got the run time error again...  Here is what I ran... 
With DestBook
    .Title = "Installment Trans History"
    .Subject = "legal Request"
    .ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, fileName:=fileName
    Set DestSheet = .Worksheets("sheet1")
End With

Answer (score 0):

You want to use `workbook.exportasfixedformat`.

The reason it isn't working is you are trying to save a pdf into a workbook. There is no need to add a new workbook, and it is failing out because that is the object you are now working off of.

```
fileName = "O:\Paula\Z test write PDF file exhibit A\" & Cells(initial + 1, 1).Text & ".pdf"

With activeworkbook 'You should make this an explicit reference to your current workbook.
    .exportasfixedformat xltypepdf, filename
end with
```

Comment: Thank you, I'll give this a try.